# Godaddy SSL on Centos 7

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, centos

i have centos installed on my server based on digitalocean, i have one standard ssl from godaddy , i followed this tutorial [LINK](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-ssl-certificate-in-rhelcentos) everything works fine to here , my commands explain in more details

first i get make private key

```
 # openssl genrsa -out mydomain.key 2048
```

then i created a new CSR file to regenrate certifacate from godaddy

```
 # openssl req -new -key mydomain.key -out mydomain.csr
```

then i copied .crt to `/etc/pki/tls/certs` and .key,.csr to `..../private/`

after that i copy .csr file to godaddy SSL manger and paste it to regenerate

now i downloaded certificate files and extract them to the server

my `httpd.conf` now looks

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key
#SSLCACertificatePath  /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
ServerName www.xxxxx.com:443
ServerAlias xxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxx.com/public_html
ErrorLog /var/www/xxxxx.com/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/xxxxx.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when i restart the server

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: So did you do as requested: `systemctl status httpd.service` and `journalctl -xe`? Did you look at Apache logfiles? Did you do an `apachectl configtest`? This is basic Apache troubleshooting and is offtopic here as not related to programming. Try [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should uncomment the line starting with `SSLCACertificatePath`  and make it like this:

```
SSLCACertificatePath  /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

If you want to point explicitly to the certificates use this format:

```
SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

This is very important file to check the validity of signature of your certificate